# Trying to create a TeamChanger with one RemoteEvent

Tags: roblox

So what I am trying to create is a TeamChanger, if a button is pressed the LocalScript fires the Server and a Script in ServerScriptService will connect on it, but I have one problem.

I want that the ServerScript to connect only to one function when the LocalScript has fired the Server (Each Join Button for the Teams fire the Same RemoteEvent)

So basically if **Button1** will be Pressed the Script will only use **Function1**

But if **Button2** will be pressed the Script will only use **Function2** and so on.

Any Ideas?

Update:

All Buttons LocalScript:

```
TR = game.ReplicatedStorage.TeamChangeRE


function buttonPressed()
    TR:FireServer()
end

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(buttonPressed)
```

Serverscript:

```
local Team = game:GetService("Teams")
local TRE = game.ReplicatedStorage.TeamChangeRE

function CDTeam(player)
    if player:IsInGroup(7465879) == 1 then
        player.Team = Team["Class-D"]
    end
end


function FPTeam(player)
    if player:IsInGroup(7465879) == 3 then
        player.Team = Team["Foundation Personnel"]
    end
end


TRE.OnServerEvent:Connect(CDTeam)
TRE.OnServerEvent:Connect(FPTeam)
```

Basically what I am trying to reach is that if a Button has been pressed, only a specific Function in the Script will fire instead of all. (Which causes that the player is getting Teamed Multiple Times)

Comment: Could you add a code sample with your issue?

Comment: Posted the Scripts below.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the scripts, not post them as answers.

Comment: I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for a RemoteEvent to only fire for one connection.

But in your example, why not just combine the functions into one?
The [player:IsInGroup() function](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Player/IsInGroup) returns a bool, not a number so you can place people in teams based on that.

```
local Team = game:GetService("Teams")
local TRE = game.ReplicatedStorage.TeamChangeRE

function joinTeam(player)
    if player:IsInGroup(7465879) then
        player.Team = Team["Class-D"]
    else
        player.Team = Team["Foundation Personnel"]
    end
end

TRE.OnServerEvent:Connect(joinTeam)
```

Comment: Last question, is there anyway to say that if a User inGroup is Higher than RoleId "3" that he gets a specific Team, If its 1 or 2 he gets The other Team

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Player/GetRankInGroup and https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Player/GetRoleInGroup